# Does reading an entire file leave the file handle open?

Tags: python, file-io, filehandle

If you read an entire file with `content = open('Path/to/file', 'r').read()` is the file handle left open until the script exits?  Is there a more concise method to read a whole file?

Answer (score 624, accepted):

The answer to that question depends somewhat on the particular Python implementation.

To understand what this is all about, pay particular attention to the actual `file` object.  In your code, that object is mentioned only once, in an expression, and becomes inaccessible immediately after the `read()` call returns.

This means that the file object is garbage.  The only remaining question is "When will the garbage collector collect the file object?".

in CPython, which uses a reference counter, this kind of garbage is noticed immediately, and so it will be collected immediately.  This is not generally true of other python implementations.

A better solution, to make sure that the file is closed, is this pattern:

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
```

which will always close the file immediately after the block ends; even if an exception occurs.

Edit:  To put a finer point on it:

Other than `file.__exit__()`, which is "automatically" called in a `with` context manager setting, the only other way that `file.close()` is automatically called (that is, other than explicitly calling it yourself,) is via `file.__del__()`.  This leads us to the question of when does `__del__()` get called?

> A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run at any point prior to program termination.

-- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203

In particular:

> Objects are never explicitly destroyed; however, when they become unreachable they may be garbage-collected. **An implementation is allowed to postpone garbage collection or omit it altogether** — it is a matter of implementation quality how garbage collection is implemented, as long as no objects are collected that are still reachable.
>
> [...]
>
> CPython currently uses a reference-counting scheme with (optional) delayed detection of cyclically linked garbage, which collects most objects as soon as they become unreachable, but is not guaranteed to collect garbage containing circular references.

-- https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types

(Emphasis mine)

but as it suggests, other implementations may have other behavior.  As an example, PyPy [has *6* different garbage collection implementations](https://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.4.x/garbage_collection.html)!

Comment: For a while, there weren't really other Python implementations; but relying on implementation details is not really Pythonic.

Comment: Is it still implementation-specific, or was it standardized already? Not calling `__exit__()` in such cases sounds like a design flaw.

Comment: @rr: see my edits; but in the off chance I missunderstood you, `__exit__()` *is* guarnateed to be called before executing the the next statement after a `with` clause,  it's `object.__del__()` (which, for `file` also calls `close()`) that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Wouldn't that use of "with" just be the same as open().read()? Basically losing the ref from the open allowing it to be GCed? Is there a difference with the with (IE, does only scope change initiate GC)? You have file.close, is this really about not wanting to keep around a useless ref to closed handle? If you want it portable GC behaviour is not predictable (even using with) so you should explicitly close surely and not rely on the GC to do that?

Comment: @jgmjgm It's precisely because of those 3 issues, GC being unpredictable, `try`/`finally` being fiddly and the highly common usefulless of cleanup handlers that `with` solves.  The difference between "explicitly closing" and "managing with `with`" is that the exit handler is called even if an exception is thrown.  You could put the `close()` in a `finally` clause, but that is not much different from using `with` instead, a bit messier (3 extra lines instead of 1), and a little harder to get just right.

Comment: What I don't get about that is why 'with' would be anymore reliable since it's not explicit either. Is it because the spec says it has to do that its always implemented like that?

Comment: @jgmjgm it's more reliable because `with foo() as f: [...]` is basically the same as `f = foo()`, `f.__enter__()`,  [...] and `f.__exit__()` *with exceptions handled*, so that `__exit__` is always called. So the file always gets closed.

Comment: @neingeist do you have citation from the docs to confirm this, or is it implementation dependent

Answer (score 119):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text).

For Python 3.5 and above:

```
from pathlib import Path
contents = Path(file_path).read_text()
```

For older versions of Python use [pathlib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2):

```
$ pip install pathlib2
```

Then:

```
from pathlib2 import Path
contents = Path(file_path).read_text()
```

---

This is the actual `read_text` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/pathlib.py#L1160):

```
def read_text(self, encoding=None, errors=None):
    """
    Open the file in text mode, read it, and close the file.
    """
    with self.open(mode='r', encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Comment: I encountered issues with this solution, maybe someone has an answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49428723/2932052)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you have to read file line by line to work with each line, you can use

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    s = f.readline()
    while s:
        # do whatever you want to
        s = f.readline()
```

Or even better way:

```
with open('Path/to/file') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do whatever you want to
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of retrieving the file content as a single string,
it can be handy to **store the content as a list of all lines the file comprises**:

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content_list = content_file.read().strip().split("\n")
```

As can be seen, one needs to add the concatenated methods `.strip().split("\n")` to [the main answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python/7409814#7409814).

Here, `.strip()` just removes whitespace and newline characters at the endings of the entire file string,
and `.split("\n")` produces the actual list via splitting the entire file string at every *newline character* **\n**.

Moreover,
this way the entire file content can be stored in a variable, which might be desired in some cases, instead of looping over the file line by line as pointed out in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python/59150605#59150605).