# Program to cipher text

Tags: python, file-io

I need to write a program that reads a cipher text.  I'm confused on how to import the needed text. Is this right? What if I have more than one cipher text to import?

```
def MultiAlphaCipher():
    import MyCipherText.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading entire file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want your program to do? What should MultiAlphaCipher() do? What exactly are you trying to import? Please edit your question.

Comment: def codeData(fileName):
    fileName = content
    content = open('IowaRosterXML.txt', 'r').read()
    return content

Comment: Never mind! I got this! Thanks for all your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just reading the contents of a plain encrypted text file:

```
def read_file():
    f=file('MyFile.txt', 'r')  ## For files like ".txt"
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    return content

file_stuff = read_file()  ## Will return the contents of "MyFile.txt" or whatever the filename is!
```

There are other conventions on reading a file like using "*open*" or "*with*", but that'll do untill you get better... 
Also, in my experience of cryptography, I suggest using a diffrrent read mode or possibly encoding.

```
f = file("MyFile.doc", "rb")  ## For files like ".pdf", ".rtf" or any file that uses font, color, etc
```

That will open the file in "read binary" mode which is helpful if you're encrypting/deceypting files outside plain ASCII. Then when writting to a file, you'll use mode "*w*" or "*wb*" to "write binary"

Hope that helps!

Additonal Tips:
If that is your actual code:

- Import is used to import modules/libraries (other programs)
- Import any module at the beginning and outside of functions/iterations

Comment: def codeData():
    f = file('IowaRoster.txt', 'r')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()

Comment: That's what I have so far.  Not sure where I'm messing up.

Comment: def codeData():
    f = open('IowaRosterXML.txt', 'r')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    return content

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer... It seems you want it inside a function...  If so, you'll have to use "return" to get the contents back to the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
with open("MyCipherText.txt") as f:
    cipher_text = f.read()
```