# How to get all the words of the doc2 in the doc1?

Tags: python, regex

How to get all the words of the doc2 in the doc1?

```
file_stop = open('doc1','r')
isi_stop = file_stop.read()
file_doc1 = open('doc2','r')
isi_doc1 = file_doc1.read()
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and define "word".

Comment: What have you tried ? I suggest you to read the answer of that question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python

Comment: How to get all the words of the doc2 in the doc1?
im sorry if i dont have complete my question.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the text of doc2 TO doc1 use:

```
with open('doc2', 'r') as doc2:
    read = doc2.readlines()
    with open('doc1', 'w') as doc2:   # Not 'r' (read), use 'w' (write)
         doc1.writelines(read)
```

Explanation (sorry if is bad):

```
open(file that you want to open, mode of opening)
# open the file with an specific mode, ('r' read, 'w' write, there are other like 'r+', 'w+', etc)
# you have to use open with a variable like:
file = open('doc1', 'r')
with open('doc1', 'r') as doc:
# you open the doc1 in the variable doc for a shot while, i mean, when you finish to use the file, it will automatly close.
read = doc2.readlines()
# you read the file (in this case 'doc2') (only can be done with reading modes [or readding and writting modes]) and load it in a variable ('read')
doc1.writelines(read)
# you write in the file ('doc1') all the text or values loaded in the variable ('read'), (you can only write in writting modes (or writting and readding)
```

I hope that it help you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: thank you for answer.
but i need to find the doc1 word in the doc 2 or vice verca.

Comment: @GilangPratama Sorry but i don't understand your question. You want to: copy the text of doc1 to doc2 or to doc2 to doc1 OR you want compare them and print its differences?.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all. Im just guessing here:

You want to read all the contents of doc1 and write them to doc2.

```
with open('doc2', 'r') as doc2:
    reader = doc2.readlines()
    with open('doc1', 'a') as doc1:
        doc1.writelines(reader)
```

Comment: thank you for answer.
but i need to find the doc1 word in the doc 2 or vice verca.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really give a try to understand your code. You should open your destination file in a write mode first to be able to write.

So your third line of code should be.

```
file_doc1=open('doc2','w')
```

and as well in your fourth line of code your are using read function where you should be using write function as you have to copy the contents of doc1 to it 
it would be as below.

```
file_doc1.write(isi_stop)
```

here you would put to doc2 what you have read from doc1.

Comment: thank you for answer.
but i need to find the doc1 word in the doc 2 or vice verca.

Comment: Dear Gilang try replacing your code with edits mentioned,You will find it working