# Why isn't it printing (file handling)?

Tags: python

I am not very sure where I have gone wrong.

I am trying to print the contents from the page in files.

Here is the code

```
File>>> If you fell down yesterday, stand up today
```

---

```
text_file = open("files.txt", "r")
print(text_file)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading entire file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python)

Comment: Do -> `print(text_file.read())` and read the link provided. It will explain everything.

Comment: [7.2 Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) from the Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [file objects documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects). An example of iterating over the file includes:

```
for line in text_file:
    print(line)
```

Or use `text_file.readlines()` to receive a list of lines:

```
['If you fell down yesterday, stand up today']
```

Comment: It keeps giving me this                                                                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    text_file = open("files.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files.txt'
exited with non-zero status

Comment: @poisonishere You're probably not in the same directory that 'files.txt' is located in. Open your terminal there or `import os` and use `os.chdir(path)`

Answer (score 0):

The way this works in Python is that it takes the file and stores it as just a file in that variable. Thus, you're trying to print a literal file, not the contents. There are a few ways to read things, assuming fvar as the file object for a text doc.

```
fulltext = fvar.read()
```

That will put the full text as a string.

```
oneline = fvar.readline()
```

Puts one line as the string oneline. Best used in loops. It will read the next line each time it runs - when it hits the end, it will return an empty string.

```
linelist = fvar.readlines()
```

This takes every line, as read with readline, and puts it into a list. Performs the same as a loop that reads each line with readline and appends each line to a list.

Hope that helps!