# Text classification - Error: 'count' is not defined

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to use the Loughran/McDonald dictionary to classify the tone of financial texts.

Here is a code I found online:

```
# Get tone dictionary

import re

with open('lmdict.txt') as list:
    lines = list.readlines()
dict = {}
for l in lines:
    if l[0:2] == '>>':
        cat = l[2:].strip()
        dict[cat] = []
    else:
        l = l.strip()
        if l:
            dict[cat].append(l)

# Set up regular expressions
regex = {}
for cat in dict.keys():
    pattern = '\\b(?:' + '|'.join(dict[cat]) + ')\\b'
    regex[cat] = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)

# Get tone count
text = "Bsp.text"

wordcount = len(text.split())
for cat in count.keys():
    count[cat] = len(regex[cat].findall(text))
print(count)
```

Few errors occured before, so I added *import re* and *text = "Bsp.text"* to assign the document which I'd like to classify as the variable **text** (I hope I did it correctly?).
Unfortunately, there is another error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M\Desktop\Python34\xWordlist.py", line 25, in <module>
    for cat in count.keys():
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

How can I fix this? I'm new to Python, so if there is any other mistake in the code, please let me know. I'd really appreciate it!

**UPDATE**: I changed the last part of the code, it is working now:

```
# Get tone count

with open('Bsp.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()


count = {}
wordcount = len(content.split())
for cat in dict.keys():
    count[cat] = len(regex[cat].findall(content))

print(count)
```

Comment: That's right, it's not defined. It's not clear why you thought it would be; where do you expect `count` to come from?

Comment: I think the variable name is wrong. You never assigned `count`. The variable assigned is `wordcount`. Where is `count` expected to be assigned?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the last part of the code.

Yet, the output is: {'negative': 0, 'positive': 0}. 
Why is it still 0? There are definitely negative and positive words from the dictionary in the text... What do I have to add to make it count? @skjoshi

Comment: @M.Civ if you have a different problem, it should be a different question.

Comment: ^ and there are a number of other problems.  To begin with, look up how to read files.

Comment: @Baldrickk Well, I will heed your advice. Would be happier if my code worked though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **count** variable is never assigned...
Perhaps you mean:

```
count = {}
for cat in dict.keys():
  ...
```

Also, I do not see any increment of your count variables. 
Perhaps:

```
count[cat] = len(regex[cat].findall(text))
```

Should be:

```
if cat not in count:
  count[cat] = 0
count[cat] += len(regex[cat].findall(text))
```

I added the '+' before the '=' sign...

Note: using `dict` as a name of a variable is not the best thing to do, as it 
might lead to unintended consequence, at best it will confuse the reader. `dict` is a built-in class to represent dictionaries.

Comment: you might want to note that "dict" is noto a good name to use, as it is the name of a python built-in.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the last part of the code.

Yet, the output is: {'negative': 0, 'positive': 0}. 
Why is it still 0? There are definitely negative and positive words from the dictionary in the text... What do I have to add to make it count? @Baldrickk

Comment: @M.Civ I edited my answer... I think you missed the increment.

Comment: @aramaki I was thinking more of:  `dict = dict(); a=dict()` resulting in `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` - a bit worse than confusing the user.

Comment: I edited the question, so you can see the 'new' code. There is another error now... do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @M.Civ is your 'regex' still a dictionary?

Comment: @aramaki yes it is

Comment: @M.Civ my proposed solution was wrong. I edited it, the counts should be first initialized. However, I am not sure this is why you got that exception...

Comment: @aramaki Ok, thank you for the help though! I appreciate it

Comment: @M.Civ also, what is 'Bsp.txt'? Is it a file name? If so, note that you are not actually reading the file content. You are reading the 'Bsp.txt' as a string. Not sure what you want.

Comment: @aramaki yes, it is the file name. How do i read the content then? Sorry, I am really new to programming. Is it with open("filename", 'r')?

Comment: @M.Civ yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python