# Taking the average of integers in a text file (using Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, text-files, average

This is my code:

```
results = [[usernme, score]]

with open("hisEasyR.txt", "a") as hisEasyRFile:
        writer = csv.writer(hisEasyRFile, delimiter='|')
        writer.writerows(results)
```

This is what the text file looks like:

```
mary|4
john|5
ben|3
```

I want to take all the integers and calculate the average. 
For example, for this file, I would want it to output:

```
The average is 4.
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `list comprehension`:

```
with open("hisEasyR.txt") as hisEasyRFile:
    numbers = [int(line.rstrip('\n').split('|')[-1])
               for line in hisEasyRFile if not line.isspace()]

print "The average is %d." % (sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
# The average is 4.
```

Comment: Hiya, sorry, I'm definietly not an expert in Python. I'm so bad at trying to correct prrograms haha. I'm getting the error `print "The average is %d." % (sum(ls) / len(ls))
NameError: global name 'ls' is not defined`

Comment: @Programmer12, sorry it was a typo. Changed it to `numbers`. Now it should work.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks! How do I go about changing the average to a float if I wanted to? I tried to change the 'int' in `numbers = [int(line.rstrip('\n').split('|')[-1])` to `float` but it didn't have any affect :)

Comment: Change `int(line.rstrip('\n').split('|')[-1])` to `float(line.rstrip('\n').split('|')[-1])`.

Comment: And in the `print` statement, change `%d` to `%f`.

Comment: If you want to truncate it to, say, two decimal places, you could do so with `%.2f`

Comment: Ah I see. Amazing! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The long way:
Read line by line, use string split on the |.
Then take the second string, (which is the number), and cast it to an int.

Refer to: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

Pseudo:

```
sum = 0

For line in file:
     mySplit = str.split(line, '|')
     sum += int(mySplit[1])

avg = sum/numLines
```

Answer (score 0):

In two lines: (assuming you already read the entire file to `content`)

```
new_list = [int(i.split("|")[1]) for i in content.split("\n") if "|" in i]
print "The average is " + str(sum(new_list) / float(len(new_list)))
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python haha. Could you give me an example of how to read the file to content?

Comment: In short:  
`with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as file:  
    content = file.read()`  
  
take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `new_list = [int(i.split("|")[1]) for i in content.split("\n")]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: what's your input? I guess the problem is with empty lines. I updated my answer