# Unexpected results from Path.read_text (of pathlib) when reading utf-8 encoded file

Tags: python, file-io, encoding, pathlib

Today I learned that for `open(filename).read()` we cannot expect that the resources bound to the hidden file object are given back immediately, although I observed this on my system. (See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409814/2932052) of the question [Does reading an entire file leave the file handle open?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7409780/2932052)).

[The second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39591569/2932052) made me resist to roll my own helper function, it told me that `pathlib` already offers exactly this function.

But actually, this seems not to be the case. With the following script (`test.py`), I get different results:

```
# The German accent characters are Ä,Ö,Ü,ä,ö,ü, and ß.
from pathlib import Path;

def pathlib_read_text(filename, encoding=None):
    return Path(filename, encoding=encoding).read_text()

def mylocal_read_text(filename, encoding=None):
    with open(filename, encoding=encoding) as f:
        return f.read()

def test(fun):
    print(fun+'_read_text:')
    print(eval(fun+'_read_text')(__file__, 'utf-8'))

test('pathlib')
test('mylocal')
```

The output to the Windows console (`python test.py`) contains `Ã",Ã-,Ão,Ã¤,Ã¶,Ã¼, and ÃY.` in the first block, when I redirect the output into a file, I get the second block wrong (In Notepad++ it's displayed `xC4,xD6,xDC,xE4,xF6,FC, and xDF` in White on Black) if the file is treated as utf-8.

Is there anything I overlooked?

I tried to examine the 3.6.3 code, but found no bug so far ...

- [read_text (1170)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2c5fed86e0cbba5a4e34792b0083128ce659909d/Lib/pathlib.py#L1170)
- [open (1152)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2c5fed86e0cbba5a4e34792b0083128ce659909d/Lib/pathlib.py#L1152)

### Edit

The following version reinforces my feeling that it's a bug in `pathlib` or in one of the underlying libraries/functions. Maybe it's only a Windows issue, where the default encoding is mostly different from `utf-8`. Now it's sufficient to run the test in a console window.

```
accents = '''
Ä,Ö,Ü,ä,ö,ü,ß
'''
from pathlib import Path;
import codecs

def pathlib_read_text(filename, encoding=None, errors=None):
    return Path(filename, encoding=encoding, errors=errors).read_text()

def mylocal_read_text(filename, encoding=None, errors=None):
    with open(filename, encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
        return f.read()

def space_it(error):
    return ' ';
codecs.register_error('space_it', space_it)

def test(fun):
    s = eval(fun+'_read_text')(__file__, 'utf-8', errors='space_it')
    print(fun+'_read_text:', s.split("\n")[1] == accents.strip())

test('pathlib')
test('mylocal')
```

It produces the following output:

```
pathlib_read_text: False
mylocal_read_text: True
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with redirecting the output to a file (I get the same output as in the console), but I can confirm that `read_text` garbles the special characters.

Comment: @Aran-Fey probably also Windows? I'm trying to [get it running on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/104z2P) with no luck so far ...

Comment: Windows 7, yes.

Comment: By the way, did you notice that `read_text` also accepts `encoding` as a parameter? That essentially did it for me.

Comment: Thanks, @Juho, for letting me know. What about making an answer of this?