# Regular expression python 4 integers followed by a space

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a file each time that there are exactly 4 integers followed by a space on a line in ht efile. I think I am almost there (looking at all questions and examples). Think I need a last push. Could anyone help me out.

The script splits all lines that start with 4 integers. It needs to only split when its just 4 integers and not more then 4.

```
import re
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
```

Try 1

```
for x in file.read().split(re.match(r"[0-9]{4}\s", file.readline())):
       print (x)
```

Try 2

```
for x in file.read().split(re.match(r"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\s", file.readline())):
       print (x)
```

try 3

```
for x in re.split(r"[0-9]{4}\s", file.read()):
    print (x)
```

Sample input

```
1020                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
1030
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
```

Wished for output is the above content split in:

```
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
```

and

```
200123242151111231                                 bla             bla                                       bla
200123331231231441                                 bla             bla                                       bla
```

Comment: What is in the test file? What results give you your current solutions? What is wrong with those results?

Comment: it also splits lines which it should not split

Comment: python 4, such a clickbait lol :D

Comment: how big is the file you're using?

Comment: 268 mb is the file it should eventually work on, but I have a testfile of 36 mb

Comment: Please show us some sample input and output.

Comment: adding sample input/output to the original question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.match(r"[0-9]{4}\s", file.readline())
```

This reads one line of the file and matches the regex against it,. `.split(...)` then uses the result of that as a static delimiter to split the entire file. This has no relation to what you want to achieve.

(it actually doesn't even do that because the entire file has already been read, but that's not the point)

Perhaps you were thinking of doing something like `.split(re.compile(...))`? In any case that doesn't work either, `str.split` doesn't deal with regexes.

Try `re.split(r"\b[0-9]{4}\s+", file.read())` to split the file into pieces separated by 4-digit numbers. The `\b` means 'word boundary' and prevents it from splitting on 4 digits that are just the ends of longer numbers. Note that if your file starts with a 4-digit number, the first piece will be empty.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Still it gives back a lot of lines that have a large integer at the start. It does not seem to take the space as a factor, the \s. 

My code looks like this now: 

for x in re.split(r"[0-9]{4}\s", file.read()):
    print (x)

for x in file.read().split(re.match(r"[0-9]{4}\s", file.read())):
   print (x)

Comment: Your code is what I had in mind, but I realise now that I answered a bit hastily because I don't think I quite understood what you're trying to do, hence I asked for sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You read the file with `readline` and it reads line by line, splitting file on newlines.

If the file is not very big, you can read it at once, e.g.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409814/580346))

and then apply the regexp.