# How to use glob on python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of files on python using glob, however it is returning zero.

the method goes:

```
def read(self,folders)
```

"folders" input contain the files needed to be looped through

I used

```
files = glob(folders)
```

Comment: `glob` only finds the file name. Files are opened with `open`

Comment: Use `code formatting`. Don't post pictures of your code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Isn't posting code as text a thousand times easier than cropping and uploading pictures of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading entire file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it, which yield the contents of each file in turn.

```
from glob import glob

class C:
    def read(self, folders):
        for file in glob(folders):
            with open(file) as f:
                yield f.read()
```

Comment: Why do you use a class here?

Comment: Because in the op `read` has a first argument of `self` which is a pretty good bet OP wants a method.