# Using methods to append text file contents into a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object

So I have a .txt file and I want to use methods within this class, `Map`, to append its contents into a `aDictionary`.

```
class Map:

    def __init__(self, dataText):
        self.dataText = dataText
        self.aDictionary = {}        

dataFile = open('data.txt', 'r')
c1 = Map(dataFile)
```

My `data.txt` file looks something like this:

> hello, world
>
> how, are
>
> you, today

and I want `aDictionary` to print this output:

```
{how: are, you: today}
```

Im not very good at manipulating files as I continue to get type errors and what not. Is there an easy way of performing this task using methods within the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to read the content of the file. Once you have the content of the file, you could create the dictionary like this (assuming `content` contains the *content* of `data.txt`):

```
content = """hello, world

how, are

you, today"""

d = {}
for line in content.splitlines():
    if line:
        key, value = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
        d[key] = value

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'you': 'today', 'how': 'are', 'hello': 'world'}
```

The idea is to iterate of over the lines using a `for` loop, then check if the line is not empty (`if line`), in case the line is not empty, split on comma (`line.split(',')`) and remove the trailing whitespaces (`str.strip`) for each of the values in the list using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Or using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
content = """hello, world

how, are

you, today"""

it = (map(str.strip, line.split(',')) for line in content.splitlines() if line)
d = {key: value for key, value in it}
print(d)
```

To read the content of the file you can do the following:

```
content = self.dataText.read()
```

**Further**

1. [Reading entire file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409780/reading-entire-file-in-python)
2. [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: I got an error of AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines' when replacing 'content' with 'self.dataText;

Comment: Ok that worked! can you please explain how your first method works? Im quite new to dictionaries and file manipulation in python. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CosmicCat Updated the answer!