# How can I allow users of my python program to provide files as command line arguments?

Tags: python, command-line

I want to write a simple python program that will take a file as an argument and an integer.
I would want it to look like this:
`simple.py myJ.json 5`

After that I want to have access to `myJ.json` and `5`arguments within my code.
Basically something that would allow me to store them as variables that I can refer to for the rest of the execution of my code within `simple.py`.

```
my_json = command.arg[1] #something like that
integer = commmand.arg[2]

integer = integer + 1
: doing things with them afterwards.
:
:
```

Comment: No it doesn't tell me how I can access the files and use its content.

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7409780/1092820)

Comment: The answer provided below answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you can use method in library called (sys) just type`from sys import argv` at the front of your code.
And know that `argv[0]` is equal to your python file name and `argv[1]` is equal to first argument and `argv[2]` is equal to second argument.
For summary of all that in this case `simple.py myJ.json 5`

```
from sys import argv
```

`argv[1]` = myJ.json
 `argv[2]` = 5

I hope that I could help you :)